# Set form action using jquery

Tags: jquery, django

Is there a way to set form action to call a url with primary key parameter. 
I have the following jquery:

```
$('#chatbox').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'fetcher' %}",
    data: {
      'search': recipient
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      list = data.list;
      id = data.id;
      $('#chatbox').find('.modal-body').text(id)
      $('#formid').get(0).setAttribute('action', "{% url 'usercreation:addmessage'  %}");

    }
  });
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('Chat with ' + recipient)
})
```

I need to include "id"  from success response of ajax as the primary key passed to action form. 
Something like {% url 'usercreation:addmessage' id %}
Is there any way?

EDIT:

AJAX resp:

```
   {'list': 'go358938: hi\r\ngo358938: heyyy\r\nraman: whatuppp\ngo358938: nm, you tell ?\ngo358938: im good \ngo358938: yoo\ngo358938: hello\ngo358938: hello\ngo358938: hi\ngo358938: a', 'id': 35}
```

Comment: What does your ajax response look like, is it JSON coming back?

Comment: @Woodrow added the response ! yes it is coming back and i need the id from that response to go in as the pk to form action.

Comment: So you want `form` id 35 to be the `action` ?

Comment: @Woodrow  so in general, i want something like {% url 'usercreation:addmessage' 35 %} to execute my django view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `JSON` was malformed, need to use `"` double quotes instead of `'` single quotes. You are also missing the `type` of `Ajax` request you're making e.g (`POST, GET`). I put together a mock example of getting your `JSON` response back and setting the `form action` with the `data.id` returned. Is this what you're looking for?

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/xp74s", // sample test to get JSON response
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    "search": ""
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var list = data.list;
    var id = data.id;
    //$('#chatbox').find('.modal-body').text(id);
    //$('#formid').get(0).setAttribute('action', "{% url 'usercreation:addmessage'  %}");
    $('#formid').attr("action", "{% url 'usercreation:addmessage' " + id + " %}"); // sets the value of the action, need to add your django code back here, etc.
    console.log($('#formid').attr('action')); // shows what the value is after being set
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formid">
</form>
```

Comment: i'm looking this to fit in this format if possible {% url 'usercreation:addmessage' 35 %}

Comment: Updated, if you can take another look. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate :)

Answer (score 0):

**Much batter way that You can use form action attr as ajax url easily.**

```
jQuery("#youfrmid").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
      var form = jQuery(this);
      let formData = jQuery(this).serialize();
      var url = form.attr('action');
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        //processData: false,
        //contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res)
        {
           // do whatever you want after success
        }
      });
});
```

Html for form

```
<form id="youfrmid">
</form>
```